# Finding a better bound for a binomial sum

Tags: real-analysis

What are the asymptotics of $S(d) = \sum_{ a_1 + \cdots + a_d} (\binom{n}{a_1, \cdots, a_d}d^{-n})^{2}$ for $d =3$? And for arbitrary $d$?

Motivation: The standard proof that a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^{d}$ is transient for $d \ge 3$ goes by showing $\sum_{n \ge 0} Pr(S_n = \vec{0})$ converges (this is the average number of return to the origin), and $Pr(S_{2n} = 0)$ happens to be
$2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n,n} \sum_{ a_1 + \cdots + a_d} (\binom{n}{a_1, \cdots, a_d}d^{-n})^{2}$. An upper bound of the form $Cn^{-d/2}$ can be given, but I want something stronger.

Comment: You can't get anything much stronger since $\mathbb{P}(S_{2n}=0)\sim 2\left(\frac{d}{4\pi n}\right)^{\frac{d}{2}},  \ n\to\infty$. Could you elaborate what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't know it was a tight bound. My question is - how do you prove that the upper bound is tight?

Comment: A proof is outlined here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68339/asymptotic-behavior-for-the-return-to-zero-of-a-simple-random-walk

Comment: @ByronSchmuland - Thanks! I've never heard of the local CLT before but I was kind of looking for a theorem of that kind...

Comment: No problem! $\quad$